# Prove that (A-B)⋃B=A if and only if B⊂A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I complete this proof :-

```
Let x be an arbitrary element of B
So, x ∈ B
So, x ∈ (A-B)⋃B
So, (x ∈ A and x ∉ B) or (x ∈ B)
So, x ∈ A or x ∈ B
So, x ∈ A⋃B
So, x ∈ A
So, B⊂A
```

Would the proof be complete here or do we have to conversely prove that if B⊂A, then (A-B)⋃B=A as well?

If yes, how do I prove that?

Also, let me know of any shorter and more efficient method of proving the part that I did

Thanks :)

Edit : Also, in my textbook, two basic methods have been followed for proving questions related to sets, one is the one in which you take x as any arbitrary element of one set and then apply logic to arrive at the result and the other one totally involves set operations, which one is better (I think the second on is cause its used in almost all high level questions) and how should I get used to the second method from the first one?

Comment: I don't think your proof is correct. That $\;x\in A\cup B\;$ it doesn't follow that $\;x\in A\;$ ...

Comment: It would probably help you spot such errors/gaps in your reasoning if you write down the justification for each step you take.  Your high level approach only attempts to prove half of the "if and only if" claim in the title, namely that the left-hand equality of sets implies the right-hand subset inclusion.

Comment: So, I also have to prove that if B⊂A, then (A-B)⋃B=A, the converse of it, right? How do I do that?

Comment: @amWhy Okay, sorry, got it...

Comment: If $B\subset A$, then  $x\in B\to x\in A$, Rajdeep

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh,right, I get it, it can be a member of B too, silly me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your proof isn't correct: $x \in A \cup B$ does not imply that $x \in A$. Rather, you have to use the fact that  $A = (A - B) \cup B$. Your third line says $x \in (A-B)\cup B$, (which equals $A$) so $x \in A$.

Yes, you do have to prove the converse, as the claim is an if and only if.

Specifically, assume $B \subseteq A$. We will prove $(A-B) \cup B = A$ by showing inclusion both ways. If $x \in (A-B) \cup B$, then $x \in A-B$ or $x \in A$. If $x \in A-B$, then clearly $x \in A$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in A$, as $B \subseteq A$. Then, $(A-B) \cup B \subseteq A$

Now, let $x \in A$. Then either $x \in B$ or $x \not \in B$. In the first case, $x \in A-B$ and in the second, $x \in B$. In either case, $x \in (A-B) \cup B$, so $A \subseteq (A-B)\cup B$.

We have now shown both inclusions, so $(A-B) \cup B = A$.

We've also shown both implications, so $B \subseteq A \iff (A-B) \cup B = A$

Comment: Got one doubt, if x∈(A−B)∪B, does that mean that x∈(A−B) or x∈B, instead you have written that x∈(A-B) or x∈A. Understood the proof for the converse perfectly...

Comment: ahh. If you *assume* that $A = (A-B) \cup B$, and you know that $x \in (A-B) \cup B$, then $x \in A$, because $A = (A-B) \cup B$. You're just substituting $A$ for $(A-B) \cup B$.